# remove uiview by uibutton programmatically

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, addsubview

I'm stuck at how to remove the uiview by user clicking the uibutton, the uibutton load at once the scene is loaded. The uibutton isn't getting response as well.
How should I set it up? Please help, thanks a lot.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    UIView *holderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, _imagePicker.selectedImage.size.width, _imagePicker.selectedImage.size.height)];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[holderView frame]];
    [imageView setImage:_imagePicker.selectedImage];
    [holderView addSubview:imageView];

    UIButton *removeSticker = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    removeSticker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100);
    [removeSticker setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel-disabled.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [removeSticker addTarget:holderView action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [holderView addSubview: removeSticker];

    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)];
    [pinchRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [holderView addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];

    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];
    [rotationRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [holderView addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
    [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [holderView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
    [tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [holderView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

    [parentPreviewView addSubview:holderView];
}

- (void) buttonClicked: (id)sender
{
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the target from `holderView` to `self`:

```
[removeSticker addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and change the code that removes the view to the following:

```
[holderView removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Good answer, assuming the original question was regarding removing `holderView`.  One suggestion I would have would be to move the `buttonClicked` method *above* the `viewWillAppear:` method, especially if `buttonClicked` is not declared in the .h interface file.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I don't think it'll matter if `buttonClicked` method is defined above or below `viewWillAppear` as long as we're using selectors.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, however when I change it to `[holderView removeFromSuperview];`, it said use of undeclared identifier?

Comment: Yes, that's because `holderView` is a local variable. You can make it a private variable, or just use the following code: `UIView *holderView = [(UIButton *)sender superView]; [holderView removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: maybe I'm not saying it clear enough, I'm making a photo decoration app, actually I want to remove the decoration sticker that has been added by the user, i.e the imageView, so should I remove the imageView instead of the holderView? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you only remove `imageView` the button and `holderView` will remain, and I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: yes thanks for clarifying, I'm a newbie here, sorry but where should I  include `UIView *holderView = [(UIButton *)sender superView]; [holderView removeFromSuperview];` ? Thanks you.

Comment: Put it in `buttonClicked` method.

Comment: I've put it in `buttonClicked` method but it said Instance method -superView not found. Please advice. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following technique.Specify tag of every control that you have at your View.Then you can get benefit from this "tag" property

suppose i specified tag as 100.   Then

```
 UIButtom *buttonToRemove=(UIButton*)[self.view   viewWithTag:100];
```

now to remove it(Buttons) use this

```
[buttonToRemove removeFromSuperview];
```